# Python parse and flatten only some fields of a dict in a list

Tags: python, dictionary

I have a JSON that I have converted to a list of python dicts that looks like so:

```
[
{'id': 8675309,
 'slug': 'name',
 'campaigns': [
   {
   'part_id': 'sfgsdfgsd',
   'client_id': '1sdfgsdfg',
   'business_id': None,
   'metadata': {'field':1}},
   {
   'part_id': '354yyr',
   'client_id': 'erty465',
   'business_id': None,
   'metadata': {'field':10}
   }
   ]
},
{'id': 1234567,
 'slug': 'name2',
 'campaigns': [
   {
   'part_id': 'wertyw',
   'client_id': 'sighs',
   'business_id': None,
   'metadata': {'field':1}}
   ]
}
```

and I basically need to flatten the `part_id`, `client_id`, and `business_id` from the `campaigns` list while maintaining the `id` and `slug` fields. Basically I'm looking for a result that looks like this:

```
[
    {
     'id': 8675309,
     'slug': 'name',
     'part_id': 'sfgsdfgsd',
     'client_id': '1sdfgsdfg',
     'business_id': None,
    },
    {
     'id': 8675309,
     'slug': 'name',
     'part_id': '354yyr',
     'client_id': 'erty465',
     'business_id': None,
    },
    {
     'id': 1234567,
     'slug': 'name2',
     'part_id': 'wertyw',
     'client_id': 'sighs',
     'business_id': None,
    }
]
```

I know how to flatten the campaign data like this:

```
campaigns = [i['campaigns'] for i in data]
campaigns = [item for sublist in campaigns for item in sublist]
```

where `data` is the list of dicts but how do I do that while maintaining the `id` and `slug` fields?

Comment: "I have a JSON that I have converted to a list of python dicts" => then you question is only about python dicts and lists - the fact you buit them from some json document is totally irrelevant.

Comment: @brunodesthuilliers totally irrelevant, just like your comment!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Give this a try. The trick is to create a base dict to perform a merge with your campaign data.

```
def squash(data):
    results = []
    for item in data:
        base = {
          'id': item['id'],
          'slug': item['slug']
        }
        for campaign in item.get('campaigns', []):
            results.append({
                **base,
                'part_id': campaign['part_id'],
                'business_id': campaign['business_id'],
                'client_id': campaign['client_id']
            })
    return results
```

Comment: great answer, thanks! it's too bad there's no way around a nested for loop

Comment: @DBA108642, if your input is huge and you want to optimize memory usage, there's a way using [`ChainMap`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/collections.html#collections.ChainMap) (*with single loop, btw*).

Answer (score 2):

You can use [`operator.itemgetter()`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/operator.html#operator.itemgetter) to get certain keys from dictionary in one expression. Then use [`zip()`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#zip) to create key-value pairs and pass them to a [`dict()`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#func-dict).

**Code**:

```
from operator import itemgetter

source = [] # YOUR SOURCE

main_fields = 'id', 'slug'
sub_fields = 'part_id', 'client_id', 'business_id'
main_getter = itemgetter(*main_fields)
sub_getter = itemgetter(*sub_fields)
result = []

for item in source:
    parsed = main_getter(item)
    for campaign in item['campaigns']:
        result.append(dict(zip(main_fields + sub_fields, parsed + sub_getter(campaign))))
```

You can also use [nested list comprehension](https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/datastructures.html#nested-list-comprehensions):

```
result = [dict(zip(main_fields + sub_fields, itemgetter(*main_fields)(item) + itemgetter(*sub_fields)(campaign))) for item in source for campaign in item['campaigns']]
```